# Implications of Venus and Mars having the same mass as Earth

Tags: planets, orbital-mechanics, astronomy, solar-system, astrophysics

Could anyone advise if there have been any simulations on the long term stability of our solar system if Venus and Mars both had the same mass as Earth ?
If not, is this something that can be answered reasonably or is it just too complicated ?

To clarify: I mean a sudden increase in Mars and Venus mass, not since the beginning of the solar system.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Venus already has 81.5% of Earth's mass. I doubt there would be a major difference if it was 1*10^24 kilograms heavier.

Comment: Mars is a _long_ way from Earth even on close approach.  If it suddenly increased in mass tenfold, that's still not a huge mass at 55 million km.  It might be a problem in millions of years, but implications for the human species would be negligible.

Comment: Computer simulations of the solar system is a topic of ongoing research.  A hypothetical mass flip would be trivial - though I doubt it would be worth publishing.  See for example this paper and its references.  Or do a search for computer solar system chaos.
 https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2022/06/aa43327-22.pdf

Comment: I read a couple scenarios, please edit to reflect what you mean, or perhaps there's something else.  1) If they had been much more massive from the beginning, what would be different?  2) Mars and Venus abruptly increase their mass to match Earth, without blowing up.  Mundane reasons like towing the asteroid belt to the surface of Mars, or wacky reasons like aliens with godlike technology turned on a gravity generator at the center of each planet.  There's consequences for each planet locally, but not much happens to Earth on the immediate timeframe.  Long term, all orbits change

Comment: Since we don’t even know if the real solar system is or is not stable in the long term, we certainly can’t tell if an alternative version would be.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to test the implications yourself using the Universe sandbox 2 software. Given that this software is available scenarios like the ones you suggest may have been attempted. I doubt anyone has published them but Google Scholar might be a good source of info on simulations on orbital mechanics or something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

The question is twofold:

1. how would behave a system with stated properties? Not much of a difference, really. Almost any combination of comparable masses could get into long term stable orbits, gently trading inclination, angular momentum and orbital energy between each other. The innermost member will always have less luck and will develop different exotic orbits over time, just like our Mercury does.
2. what else could be different in order for such a system to form? Planets compete for mass as they develop and at different stages they compete for different substances. They also migrate in and out. One can bet that they will get different amount of volatiles (water, carbon, nitrogen...). Gas giants may be of less mass (or not?)